# How to create CEP for Adobe InDesign

Tags: javascript, plugins, adobe-indesign

For last days I am trying to create and run CEP for Adobe Indesign. I followed this steps [https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTlkT.png)

I think everything work fine until the point 6 "Launch your extension in the host app" In my Window there is no Extension option. Where I should search for my CEP?

[image]
I created my main folder in Adobe folder on the same level as folders Indesign Photoshop ...

Comment: Are you able to run your extension (or in this case "script") from the Scripts panel?

Comment: Probably something is wrong with CEP folder? See here: https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/CEP_8.x/Documentation/CEP%208.0%20HTML%20Extension%20Cookbook.md#extension-folders